# vue.js - close modal when update

Tags: vue.js

Here is my architecture :

```js
Vue.component('center-view', {
  props: ["center"],
  template: `
    <ul style="border: 1px black solid">
      <li>Center : {{ center.name }}</li>
      <li v-for="p in center.people">
        {{ p }}
        <button>Affect this user to another center (modal)</button>
      </li>
    </ul>`
});

new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    centers: []
  },
  created: function () {
    this.refreshData();
  },
  methods: {
    refreshData: function() {
      // (actually, an ajax request here)
      this.centers = [{
          name: "Paris",
          people: ["Seb", "Eric"]
        },
        {
          name: "NY",
          people: ["Edmond", "Nath"]
        }
      ];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
      <center-view 
        :center="center"
        v-for="center in centers"
       ></center-view>
</div>
```

The `<button>` will be replace by a modal.

Here what I would like:

1. By default the modal's state is "hidden" and only a button is shown
2. When the user click on that button, the modal's state becomes
   "visible" and the entire modal is shown.
3. The user can  affect the people to another center and validate by clicking a button (in the modal), this button emits an event caught by
   root.
4. The root component make an ajax request to the server to update the affectations.

   4.a If this request is succesfull, the root component apply a "refreshData" and the modal is closed

   4.b Else, the modal is not shown and an error message is shown in this modal.

I'm stuck at the **steps 4.a/b**. : the only solution I see is to put the state of all modals in the root component. It seems a bit uggly to me (the root component doesn't care about the modal is visible or not).

Comment: Yes, my issue wasn't very clear. I've update my question. Hope it's better.

Comment: But your issue is about displaying your modal so where is the modal in your code ?

Comment: No it's not about displaying the modal, it's more about "how to hide it when the ajax request is done". I didn't put the code of the modal in order to let the code clear

Comment: if you need to hide the modal, you need to display it first. you talk about your modal's state but where do you define it ? in a store ? in the component 'Modal' ? after your request you simply return the modal's state to false with a method or a mutation